# ImageMagick not working. "Call to undefined function NewMagickWand()"

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

I installed *ImageMagick* following the instructions on [this site](http://www.theatons.com/install-imagemagick-imagick-for-php-on-ubuntu).

When I check my **phpinfo()** there is a whole section on imagick now.

```
imagick module  enabled
imagick module version  3.0.1
imagick classes Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
ImageMagick version ImageMagick 6.5.7-8 2010-12-02 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright   Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date    2010-12-02
ImageMagick number of supported formats:    202
```

However when I try to use it I get this error:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function NewMagickWand()**

I have never used image magick before.

Did I not install it right? Is there more extensions I need to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `MagickWand` module/extension installed for it to work. See: http://www.magickwand.org/

Comment: Thanks, the instructions say to download a file and I only have ssh capabilities so I have asked the server admins to install magickwand. Hopefully that solves it.